# Union All para Entity framework utilizando Lambda

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, expressões-lambda, union-all

Estou com problemas em uma consulta utilizando lambda e Entity Framework em C#. 
Quando transformo uma consulta sql simples em lambda funciona perfeitamente, conforme exemplo abaixo.

**Consulta SQL**

```
    public DataSet ListarRecebidos()
    {
        ch.Conectar();
        string sql = "";
        sql = "SELECT * FROM SCEBD019 WHERE CLIMOVI>='"+VCLIMOVI+"' AND CLIPAGO <='"+VCLIPAGO+"'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ch.cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ch.Desconectar();
        return ds;
    }
```

**Consulta Lambda**

```
public object ListarContasRecebidas(DateTime dataMovi, DateTime dataPagamento) => context.sCEBD019s.Where(c => c.CLIMOVI >= dataMovi && c.CLIPAGO <= dataPagamento).Select(c => new { c.PRONOTA, c.CLIPAGO, c.CLIRAZA, c.CLIVPAG, c.PAGCODI, c.PAGNOME, c.CARNOME, c.CLIMOVI, c.CLIPROC, c.CLIVENC, c.CLIREFE, c.CLICHEQ, c.CLIBANC, c.CLIOBSE, c.FUNCODI, c.CLIDUPL}).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Agora, uma consulta sql com o uso do *UNION ALL* eu não consigo fazer de jeito nenhum em lambda. Já procurei em vários fóruns, mas não vi ninguém usando lambda, apenas LINQ.

Se alguém tiver alguma dica ou sugestão eu agradeço muito, pois já perdi um bom tempo com isso. Não precisa nem ser resposta ou código pronto, só um norte já é o suficiente.

**Segue abaixo a consulta sql utilizando o *UNION ALL***

```
public DataSet ListarTodos()
    {
        ch.Conectar();
        string sql = "";
        sql = "SELECT * FROM SCEBD018 where SCEBD018.CLICODI='"+VCLICODI+"' AND SCEBD018.CLIMOVI>='"+VCLIMOVI+"' " +
            "AND SCEBD018.CLIVENC<='"+VCLIVENC+"' UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM SCEBD019 WHERE " +
            "SCEBD019.CLICODI = '"+VCLICODI+"' AND SCEBD019.CLIMOVI >= '"+VCLIMOVI+"' AND " +
            "SCEBD019.CLIVENC <= '"+VCLIVENC+"')";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ch.cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ch.Desconectar();
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: ao meu ver o que você está procurando é o concat ex: (select 1).Concat(select 2)

Comment: @LucasMiranda, já tentei usar o concat, conforme o trecho de código a seguir: public object ListarTodos(DateTime dataMovi, DateTime dataVenc, int codigoCliente) => context.sCEBD018s.ToList().Concat(context.sCEBD019s.ToList());, mas obtenho o seguinte erro: Erro CS1929 "List<SCEBD018>" não contém uma definição para "Concat" e a melhor sobrecarga do método de extensão "Queryable.Concat<SCEBD019>(IQueryable<SCEBD019>, IEnumerable<SCEBD019>)" requer um receptor do tipo "IQueryable<SCEBD019>"

Comment: Vc já deve ter resolvido, mas o concat vem antes do ToList() o último efetiva a consulta na base e traz o resultado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o "AddRange". Segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
List<SuaTabela> listaGeral = new List<SuaTabela>();
List<SuaTabela> lista1 = new List<SuaTabela>();
List<SuaTabela> lista2 = new List<SuaTabela>();

lista1 = contexto.SuaTabela.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ...").ToList();
lista2 = contexto.SuaTabela.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ...").ToList();

listaGeral.AddRange(lista1);
listaGeral.AddRange(lista2);
```